# Deploy ReactJs + MySQL + NodeJs Express project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, rest

I'm newbie on ReactJs and NodeJs. Before using php programming language I was just uploading to cpanel and creating database on traditional hosting. Now project has finished. But I came across concepts like Azure, Aws and Heroku. My project working like this structure:
Front-end : Reactjs
Back-end : Nodejs express rest api with mysql(CRUD)

Project works fine locally. And i don't know anything what to do. I searched Azure and Heroku but it is very complicated. What is the difference between them? And i will use send mail. How can i do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a beginner, just looking to get your feet wet, I'd recommend deploying your entire app to Heroku.

First make a Heroku account.

To deploy your react API, you'll want to follow this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Next you'll want to deploy the database itself as an app addon:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#provisioning-the-shared-mysql-add-on

Lastly, you'll deploy the react app itself:
https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration

This is only one of many approaches you can use.

If you wanted to get more "hands-on" you could deploy this API to on Amazon Web Services with separate services for the database, NodeJS API and the React frontend.

https://dev.to/asim_ansari7/deploy-a-react-node-app-to-production-on-aws-2gdf

This should serve as a good basis for that and you will learn a lot more than with the Heroku approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jordan. Well, can I transfer my own domain after these steps? Is it free ? My site must be send mail and must be store max record 500. It's not big project and i don't know about pricing.

Comment: And can i deploy this project on cpanel ? According to my research, this is possible. But does this make sense?

Comment: That would depend on the panel. Most panels only support PHP, not NodeJS. In that case, you'd need to follow an approach above. As you also want email, you'll need to look into an email provider as well, or continue using your existing one. Pricing on heroku should be very cheap for the above tutorial. Take a look at the links in my answer.

Comment: Yes you can  do that

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I am another newbie, I have a react js + mysql + express and also I already have a vm in azure with mysql installed on it, how can I deploy my app to azure vm? thanks.